# CameraX setMaxResolution can only be called from the same library group

Tags: android, image, android-camerax

I was trying to set a max resolution to my image capture usecase using the builder. In the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration#specify-resolution) it suggests to use `setTargetResolution`

But in the java doc for `setTargetResolution` it says

> The actual image resolution will be the closest available resolution in size that is not smaller than the target resolution, as determined by the Camera implementation

which is opposite of what I want. I don't want **not smaller**, I want **not larger**. I was checking the methods and saw there is `setMaxResolution` but that method while working perfectly when I build my project is annotated with `@RestrictTo(Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)` which is creating a lint error in my project.

I can suppress this error and go on with my life but I would rather understand why this was made this way. Any ideas ?

Does anyone see any risk of using `setMaxResolution` and suppressing the lint error ?